# Implementing Spring Integration logging-channel-adapter for monitoring all the applications

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I want to implement `logging-channel-adapter` in java class which monitors all the inbounds and outbounds of all the applications. If there is any another way of logging spring integration calls please advice.

Note : I am using spring boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring integration provides option to configure [global Wire Tap](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/htmlsingle/#channel-global-wiretap). That is what you want.

**Reaction on comment:**

[Here is example project I created](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/tree/master/08-integration/0835-channel-wire-tap-xml).

Comment: @luboskmac can you provide any example link

Comment: @luboskrnac may be I shouldnt expect an easy example for free?

Comment: @KrisSwat, I didn't get you question. Example is open source on Github, It is simple example I created for a Spring related book I wrote. Yes, it is slighly outdated, but I believe it is still relevant.

Comment: @luboskrnac Sorry, wanted to test wire-tap project alone, but it needed 2 more project. [parent etc]. my wire-tap code started working.thanks